# Laravel eloquent HasMany type error at include in controller

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a Customer model with many Loans records related by `idecli` Varchar field in both tables.

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'tblcli';
    protected $primaryKey = 'idecli';

    public function loans() {
        return $this->hasMany(Loan::class,'idecli','idecli');
    }
```

```
class Loan extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'tblmca';
    protected $primaryKey = 'ide';

    public function customer(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Person::class,'idecli', 'idetrc');
    }

}
```

The type of `idecli` field is varchar, however, eloquent retrieves that column as type Integer. I assume that it assumes the type by the content of the column that contains numbers inside a varchar.
In such a way that when retrieving the relationship, it generates a type error in the SQL query.
If I perform the query through an SQL tool, postgres returns a Varchar, but it seems that Eloquent transforms it into an Integer.

```
            $customers = Customer::where('salcli','>',0)
            ->with('loans')
            ->paginate($perPage);
```

And error:

```
{
    "message": "SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  el operador no existe: character varying = integer\nLINE 1: select * from \"tblmca\" where \"tblmca\".\"idecli\" in (63282672,...\n                                                       ^\nHINT:  Ning\u00fan operador coincide en el nombre y tipos de argumentos. Puede ser necesario agregar conversi\u00f3n expl\u00edcita de tipos. (SQL: select * from \"tblmca\" where \"tblmca\".\"idecli\" in (63282672, 63484298, 91003258, 1001871607, 1005461867, 1006407380, 1095809492, 1098737988, 1098801653, 1102366442))",
    "exception": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException",
```

Comment: Should this `$this->belongsTo(Person::class,'idecli', 'idetrc')` instead be `$this->belongsTo(Customer::class,'idecli', 'idetrc')`

Comment: Thanks, I already made the change but it still generates the same error. For some reason, Eloquent converts the idecli field to integer, being really varchar.```select * from tbltrc where "tbltrc"."idetrc" in (63282672,63484298)``` instead of ```select * from tbltrc where "tbltrc"."idetrc" in ('63282672','63484298')```

Comment: Try adding `$incrementing = false;` to your model, should stop it from thinking PK is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel eloquent assumes that the primary key is **numeric**, since it is **necessary** to inform the model that the key is type **string** type. Works fine!

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use EloquentJoin;

    protected $table = 'tblcli';
    protected $primaryKey = 'idecli';
    protected $keyType = 'string';
...
}
```

Comment: You could have just set `public $incrementing = false;`

Comment: Don't work. Only work with: ```protected $keyType = 'string';```